# JAVA Desktop Application for Database System

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've been told to make a Database for office inventory, well as a student that not excel at coding yet, I've came up with Desktop App that I will create with JAVA Netbeans (SWING), as it's quite easy for designing the GUI, and for the database design, I'm using XAMPP PhpMyadmin (local host).

Now, the real problem is that I only can access the system on my PC only, with opening XAMPP, and run it through Netbeans. May I know how can I make my system accessible from another PC ? As well as the database, how can I make my database accessible without opening XAMPP??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way for building Java Desktop application which requires database, is using embedded database. It means that whenever you run java application the database is running too.
So making accessible database without opening XAMPP, the solution could be using embedded database.
Some of embedded database are:

- SQLite
- Derby
- H2
- HSQLDB

Another solution could be making database on real server or on office server and connecting from there, but not on localhost server.